# Yesod - the best way to create users on the web site?

Tags: haskell, authentication, yesod

I'm trying to develop a site, where users will be registered directly on it, as opposed to being authenticated by Google mail etc.  Beside the usual username/password I need to collect more data from the user - name, address, etc.  What would be the quickest way for adding the desired functionality?  Short of writing my own Auth plugin I see two options:

1. Create my own registration form (which I kinda need to do anyway) and use HashDB for storing the passwords and later authentication.  However, yesod.auth.hashdb seems to be gone from the latest version (why?) and is only available separately here: https://github.com/ollieh/yesod-auth-bcrypt/ .  Is something wrong with it?  Security flaws?
2. Use http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-auth-account - looks much closer to what I need, because it already provides registration page, but it doesn't seem to be supported by the latest yesod 1.2.5 and it is not clear how to integrate my additional fields into the existing registration process

Comment: how you solved this ? - I have a similar problem, solution would be very helpful.

Comment: I haven't, to be honest.  Had to give up yesod altogether - I don't think it is mature enough for real world stuff.  It's a petty, because the idea is so nice.

Comment: All you need is just to user few authPlugins to have both authorization types. Yesod is very robust.